# Next.js Flashing with Ant Design on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am currently developing a website utilizing Next.js and Ant Design and I have found a Chrome only issue that I am unable to fix. Whenever the user leaves the page or leaves the chrome window and returns, there is a brief flash of black on every page of the website. Furthermore, it seems that CSS styles are not being loaded fast enough, because when the website is reloaded, it is possible to see an enlarged version of my SVG logo before it is properly resized, which is very distracting. These issues only persist on Chrome to my knowledge as I have tested it with Safari and Firefox and have been unable to reproduce this issue. I have looked around for a solution, but they all use styled-components as well as a `_document.js` file in their project to solve the issue, but I have neither currently. Any help would be great on this, the relevant code will be below, if anything else is needed I can provide more. (Not every bit is used, I did use a tutorial to set learn how next.js worked so there are remnants of that).

EDIT: I want to add that the css flash/black flash happens on refresh of the page or when the window is deselected or minimized. I am still unsure if this is a problem with Next.js or if it is a problem with my implementation of the global css file with Ant Design.

EDIT 2: This problem is still an issue and I have been still unable to fix it...It's not too serious but it is annoying for chrome users I have found when doing alpha testing.

_app.js

```
import '../styles/global.css'
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Provider } from '../contexts/countryContext'

//There is a chrome only issue where the CSS Elements flash for like half a second when the page is loaded, not sure how to fix.
export default class MyApp extends App {
    render() {
      const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
          <Head>
            
          </Head>
            <Provider>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Provider>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

global.css

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

:root {
  --primary-color: #8497f5;
  --light-secondary: #A0AAEC;
  --light-tertiary: #5467DE;

  --dark-secondary: #474C69;
  --dark-tertiary: #4554B5;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #0070f3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

index.js

```
import {Layout, Row, Spin, Divider} from 'antd'
import {Component, useState, useContext} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import {Context} from '../contexts/countryContext'
import layout from '../styles/layout.module.css'
import utils from '../styles/utils.module.css'

import SiteHeader from '../components/siteHeader'
import CalculationCard from '../components/CalculationCard'
import CookieHeader from '../components/CookieHeader'

const { Header, Content, Sider, Footer } = Layout;

const Main = () =>  {
  const context = useContext(Context)

    return (
      <Layout style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}>
        
        <SiteHeader/>
        <Content className={layout.container}>
          <header className={layout.header}>
            <Link href="countrySelector">
              <img src={context.flag + ".png"} className={layout.headerImage}/>
            </Link>
            <h1 className={utils.heading2Xl}>{context.name}</h1>
          </header>

          <CookieHeader/>
        </Content>

        <Content>
          <Row gutter={16}>
          <Divider orientation="left" style={{fontSize: "1.15rem", lineHeight: 0}}>Economic</Divider>


            <CalculationCard name={"Maintenance"} desc={"Land and Naval Mintenance"} img={"local_reg_cost_icon"} link="maintenance"/>
            <CalculationCard name={"Development Cost"} desc={"Mana Costs for Development"} img={"dev_cost"}/>



          
          </Row>
        </Content>
        {/* <Footer style={{height: "100%"}}>
          Indev
        </Footer> */}
      </Layout>


    );
  }

  export default Main;
```